# Problema MYSQL sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

Cuando hago consultas con algunas tablas me sale este error. (En ubuntu)

> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Mi profesor dice que es un error de instalación.. Gracias por la yuda

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que te esté dando ese error porque hayas activado `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` con este comando:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

Entonces:

A. Prueba a desactivarlo con esto:

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

B.Trata de ejecutar de nuevo la consulta que antes te daba error.

Si sigue dando error edita tu pregunta colocando la consulta en cuestión. Quizá haya un problema de ids duplicados en la columna por la que quieres agrupar.

Answer (score 0):

el verdaderos problema no es la instalacion, si no es la configuracion "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" ya que obliga a que todos los campos a los que se les aplica el GROUP_BY esten explicitos en la lista de campos del select ó que se agregue campos de la lista del select al la clausula group by(probando lo descubriras), por lo cual o cambia la consulta para que tenga los campos presentes el el group by o cambia la consulta a Distinct o desactivar el sql_mode= only_full_group_by